# 4-layer video experimenter's board layout, critique sought

Tags: analog, adc, dac, video, pcb-layers

This is a layout for an ADV7184 video DAC, connected to an ADV7341 video encoder. The intention is to allow a microcontroller such as an Arduino or STM32 to generate text and graphics over the video image, by means of the ADV7184's support for SCART RGB overlay. I also hope to use the support for teletext and VBI as a channel for sending digital data to receivers. I have tried to replicate the layout of the ADV7184 evaluation board as much as possible, while removing the FPGA and unnecessary connectors.

I would really appreciate it if some of the experts here would critique my board layout and point out if I'm making any obvious mistakes. My priorities are first to reduce/mitigate crosstalk and second to reduce EMI.

The stack-up is as follows: signal (top) - GND - Power - signal. I have put a copper pour on the top layer.

In particular I would like guidance on the following (related) questions:

1. Will my use of a copper polygon around the 27MHz LLC (line locked clock) on the bottom layer be effective in preventing coupling with other traces and power/gnd?
2. Would it be advantageous to put GND "fingers" between the video output traces?
3. Similarly, would it be advantageous to put fingers separating the LLC from other traces?
4. Will a copper pour on the top layer as I have done be advantageous or not?
5. Are there any issues/possible improvements to decoupling?
6. Any other issues/suggestions?

[image: layout]

Below are schematics:
[image: ADC section]
[image: DAC/power section]

Thanks!

Comment: Your board doesn't look too bad. Is the GND layer hidden? Because I only see 3 layers.

regarding ground fingers: always try to ground your fingers with as many vias as possible. Especially at the ends. Open ended ground fingers can function as resonators which can make things even worse. However, with 27 MHz I wouldn't worry too much about this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes the GND layer is hidden, it is a contiguous plane. As such I'm wondering if there is benefit in having an additional GND pour on the top layer?